# Can a wireshark capture include metadata advising users of the terms of its use?

Tags: wireshark, privacy

We have a group of users who need to see the payloads of packets in wireshark captures.  I'm looking for a way to remind them users that the data contained within may not represent the exact frames on the wire (because the capture will have been pre-processed by the time they get it to remove, e.g. security-sensitive IP addresses).  A hook in the capture file that triggered a popup with a short message would be perfect.  Is there anyway to do this, short of wrapping Wireshark with another binary (which would be trivially bypass-able anyway)?

I've searched in the wireshark lists but come up empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you could do would be to have the pre-processing program write out the file in pcapng format and add a comment to the initial Section Header Block giving that warning.  That won't produce a popup - but, then, not all the capture file reading programs in the Wireshark suite are GUI programs that *could* produce a popup.